# Problem accessing Microsoft Graph from Outlook addin

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

I am trying to call Graph from within an Outlook VSTO addin. The code is below.

If I compile it into a simple Windows form application (not an addin) it works fine on the development computer and on the client's computer.

If I use the identical code in a simple VSTO addin, it works fine on the development computer, but on the client's computer (the same one where the forms application works), the call to `graphClient.Me.GetAsync` runs into an exception with the message `InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed.`

Any suggestions on what the issue might be, or how to track it down?  Thanks.

```
{
    internal class Graph
    {
        public static async void initializeGraph()
        {
            Microsoft.Graph.Models.User me = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.User();
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
            var interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = "common",
                ClientId = "[client Id here]",
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            };
            var tokenCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(tokenCredential, scopes);
            try
            {
                me = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();  //Exception here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            MessageBox.Show($"Hello {me?.DisplayName}!");
        }
    }
}
```